# rows append not working with loops

Tags: python, html, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code below is OK until I add the "trainer" field to the scrape.This field is the second part of the second sibling in the html and represents Line2.The other fields represent Line 1 in the source.I get the desired 189 lines of code out but when I  include code to extract the trainer then I only get the last dog in each race(excludes all other 5 dogs).which is only 18 lines of code.For some reason BS isn't working properly with the loops.The inclusion of the trainer field is disrupting the rows.append.Here is the url
http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135754
here is the code

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


html = requests.get("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135754").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

rows = []
for header in soup.find_all("div", class_="resultsBlockHeader"):
    track = header.find("div",    class_="track").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")
    date = header.find("div",   class_="date").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")
    datetime = header.find("div", class_="datetime").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")
    grade = header.find("div", class_="grade").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")
    distance = header.find("div", class_="distance").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")
    prizes = header.find("div", class_="prizes").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")

    results = header.find_next_sibling("div",  class_="resultsBlock").find_all("ul", class_="line1")
    for result in results:
        fin = result.find("li", class_="fin").get_text(strip=True)
        greyhound = result.find("li", class_="greyhound").get_text(strip=True)
        trap = result.find("li", class_="trap").get_text(strip=True)
        sp = result.find("li", class_="sp").get_text(strip=True)
        timeSec = result.find("li", class_="timeSec").get_text(strip=True)
        timeDistance = result.find("li", class_="timeDistance").get_text(strip=True)


    results = header.find_next_sibling("div",  class_="resultsBlock").find_all("ul", class_="line2")
    for result in results:
         trainer = result.find("li",  class_="trainer").get_text(strip=True)



    rows.append({
            "track": track,
            "date": date,
            "greyhound": greyhound,
            "datetime":datetime,
            "sp" :sp,
            "grade":grade,
            "distance":distance,
            "prizes":prizes,
            "timeSec":timeSec,
            "timeDistance":timeDistance,
            "trap":trap,
            "fin":fin,
            "trainer":trainer

        })




with open("greyfile.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,      ["track","date","trap","fin","greyhound","datetime","sp","grade","distance","prizes","timeSec","timeDistance","trainer"])

    for row in rows:
      writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I copied your code and it ran without issue, putting everything in the CSV file including trainer. (Python 2.7, bs4 with lxml, Ubuntu 15.10)  Example first line `Sheffield,02/02/16,4,6,Unique Boycie,18:39,3/1,A4,500m,"1st 100, Others 30  Race Total 250",4.34,30.22 (1 3/4),(Trainer:J D Davy)`  What error are you experiencing?

Comment: HI CasualDemon.How many lines did you get in the csv file.There should be 186 lines reflecting all of the races at the venue,but I am only getting 16 lines.It is only including the details(including trainer) of the last dog in each race.

Comment: Ah, I see, I only get 16 lines. Thanks for that clarification, I thought an exception was raised or something. I will look further into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that before you had the `rows.append` under the second for loop, so to replicate that behavior with both of those is below.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


html = requests.get("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135754").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

rows = []
for header in soup.find_all("div", class_="resultsBlockHeader"):
    track = header.find("div",    class_="track").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")
    date = header.find("div",   class_="date").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")
    datetime = header.find("div", class_="datetime").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")
    grade = header.find("div", class_="grade").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")
    distance = header.find("div", class_="distance").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")
    prizes = header.find("div", class_="prizes").get_text(strip=True).encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip("|")

    results = header.find_next_sibling("div",  class_="resultsBlock").find_all("ul", class_="line1")
    details = []
    for result in results:
        fin = result.find("li", class_="fin").get_text(strip=True)
        greyhound = result.find("li", class_="greyhound").get_text(strip=True)
        trap = result.find("li", class_="trap").get_text(strip=True)
        sp = result.find("li", class_="sp").get_text(strip=True)
        timeSec = result.find("li", class_="timeSec").get_text(strip=True)
        timeDistance = result.find("li", class_="timeDistance").get_text(strip=True)
        details.append({"greyhound": greyhound, "sp": sp, "fin": fin, "timeSec": timeSec, "timeDistance": timeDistance, "trap": trap, })

    results = header.find_next_sibling("div",  class_="resultsBlock").find_all("ul", class_="line2")
    for index, result in enumerate(results):
        trainer = result.find("li",  class_="trainer").get_text(strip=True)
        details[index]["trainer"] = trainer

    for detail in details:
        detail.update({"track": track, "date": date, "datetime": datetime, "grade": grade, "prizes": prizes})
        rows.append(detail)

with open("greyfile.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,      ["track","date","trap","fin","greyhound","datetime","sp","grade","distance","prizes","timeSec","timeDistance","trainer"])

    for row in rows:
      writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hi Casual Demon.I have added to the code and asked a seperate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442016/csv-file-unable-to-handle-html-code-in-bs-scrape